# How to use auto-increment integer user ids for firebase tokens

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt

Is it possible to change those random UIDs strings in firebase to an integer?

I am using firebase tokens to authenticate on my back-end. In my back-end I also have a table which stores additional user data required for my application. This table has a user id column which is an integer primary key and also an additional `firebase_id` field to know which firebase uid corresponds to this user. Each time there is an authenticated request on my backend, the firebase token is sent and my backend uses the `uid` field to look up `firebase_id == uid` to get the matching user in my backend or create if it does not exist. I would like to get rid of `firebase_id` and make `uid` be an integer so that instead of querying `firebase_id` I can query the integer primary key of the users table.

Is this possible?
Or are there any alternatives?

I want to do this for performance reasons, if that matters.

Comment: Answer on whether this is possible below. Before digging into alternatives: did you measure the performance difference of this lookup? I have a feeling this might be a case of [premature optimization](https://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization) as the overhead of this lookup is likely outweighed by many other factors (such as network roundtrips).

Comment: Indeed this popped into my mind while I was writing the question. Honestly I don't think the performance difference is significant enough. I guess this was also a case of prematurely asking questions haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UID of a user is determined by the authentication provider that creates that user. None of the built-in providers allow you to control the UID that is created, so you're out of luck there.

What you **can** do is create your own authentication provider and use that with Firebase. The UID is then under your control.